# Ruble & Currency delimiters

Tags: правописание, культура

On many a website from Russia and Belarus I can see prices on products displayed as:

> 212,00 p.

I've added a screen shot as well.

Is the price 212 rubles or is it a shortening or a delimiter of some sort? (like 212k meaning 212,000)

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about Russian language

Comment: One U.S. dollar is roughly 60 Russian rubles or 2 Belarusian rubles.

Comment: it IS about Russian language because in Russian in particular periods of decimal fractions and of complex numbers over 1000 are delimited differently than they are in English

Comment: Can you explain the rules of delimiting numbers in Russian please? This is exactly the meaning of the question

Comment: Instead of the decimal point we use a decimal comma. :) Thus the price in the screen shot is 212 roubles, not 212K. As a thousand delimiter we use a (thin) space: 1 000 000 is 1M.

Comment: @user13107 please update your question so that it's clear what you are asking about.

Comment: A comma as a decimal (floating) point delimiter. A dot *might* (*or* might be not) used as a thousands' delimiter; the most often-used thousands' delimiter is space (thin/narrow one preferrable).

Comment: The dot _was_ the common thousands delimiter not so long ago. However, during the last decade it got largely replaced by a space.

Comment: Quiet so, however, there was no actual standard for thousands separators in the sense today's CLDR implies (likewise, for the date-written-in-numbers formatting). Dot wasn't 'replaced' by space, only dislodged, and surely not only 'in the last decade' (and *I believe* there are still publications with 'dotted thousands' -- I see more 'thousands' in scientific notation anyway).

Comment: `As a thousand delimiter we use a (thin) space: 1 000 000 is 1M.` Do we? in school we used dot for this (granted in schools we use pen and paper, not regular computer/typewriter printing). Using space is a novelty targeted at using computer programs that - being mostly USA-targeted - tend to mistake thousands-separating dot for decimal-separating dot. And that is the reason we grew to violate rules of "Russian delimiting" and use incorrect space instead of correct comma. PS. I do like this de facto convention, but if we would talk about "rules of Russian" then we should talk about rules.

Comment: Use of space instead of a dot was promulgated in [ISO_31-0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_31-0) standard, which was published in 1992 (so @yury10578 is correct in his dating). What happened in the last decade is that switch from dot to space has become massive. I also believe that in many Russian classrooms teachers still use dots to separate thousands.

Comment: Use of space instead of dot for "easying the reading of big numbers" was being tentatively recommended for scientific (well, physics) texts yet in 1978. I can't remember what kind of separator I myself learned in the beginning, only in the higher grades it was space for sure (but not strictly required).

Comment: Dots have clear advantage over spaces in handwriting (and black/whiteboard writing). In early 1990s I knew teachers used only dots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `рубль` is commonly abbreviated as `руб.` or `р.`, so `212,00 р.` means `212 рублей`.  On websites which sell things, рубль is often abbreviated for simplicity of programming. You don't need to program the server to use the correct case each time (21 рубль, 22 рубля, 25 рублей).

In Russian, comma is used to delimit the integer and fractional parts, e.g., the familiar approximation to pi in Russian would be written as `3,14`.  On the other hand, rubles and kopecks can be also delimited by a period (for example, 3 rubles 62 kopecks was 3.62). I would say that all of the following are common: `212,00 р.`, `212.00`, `212,00`, `212 руб. 00 коп.`

The price of 212 Belarussian rubles (about $100) is pretty typical for a mattress.

Comment: Why do you say that rubles and kopecks ***should be*** separated by a period, not by a "decimal comma"?  Prices are just another example of numbers with decimal fractions. Here is an [example of a price list.](http://prokazan.ru/userfiles/images/image-04-2015/obschaya_sravn.jpg)

Comment: Here is another example, and there are tons of examples like this: http://businesspskov.ru/rmarket/shops/113742.html .  I don't know what idiot invented the decimal comma, but at least with rubles it is not that widespread.

Comment: it should have been "**can be separated by the period**". "Should" means that there is a rule for this etc, but you said in the previous paragraph that the rule clearly requires the comma, not the period. In practice, yes, in many cases the perion *can* be used for this.

Comment: @user907860 I don't like the decimal comma, but fixed it anyways.

Comment: Comma vs. point in prices and such means only that computer equipment goes with the informatics (read: English) standard of marking the decimal point. Prices and money quantities weren't traditionally written in floating point, but broken down to the monetary units (like: "X рублей 10,345678 копеек", if you wanted to be "precise").

Comment: in soviet paper hand-filled forms roubles and kopecks were often separated by a dash, to bring here yet more example. In the end it is more about conventions than rules, about expressing an idea with no ambiguity. Granted, specific documents (standard forms) may really have their local rules how to fill them. But those would hardly be rules of the language or of the state.

Comment: @user31264 i'm not sure a receipt printed out on equipment most likely manufactured abroad to the Anglo-Saxon culture or international standards could be a reliable evidence of conventions which exist in the Russian speaking culture, the users simply may not be committed or scrupulous enough to reconfigure its default setup and the management just doesn't give a damn

Comment: Soviet receipts were also with decimal points.